# StringBetweenString function

Tags: ios, string, macos, swift

I need to get substring between two strings from my text. For example, I have text "http://google.com" and I want to get substring between "://" and ".".

I don't know, how I can do that.

I try to use regular expressions, but I think, it's bad way.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A couple of options:

1. Regular expressions work well. See ICU User Guide: [Regular Expressions](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp)

   Example:

   ```
   let us = "http://google.com"
   let range = us.rangeOfString("(?<=://)[^.]+(?=.)", options:.RegularExpressionSearch)
   if range != nil {
       let found = us.substringWithRange(range!)
       println("found: \(found)") // found: google
   }
   ```

   Notes:

   ```
       (?<=://) means preceded by ://  
       [^.]+    means any characters except .  
       (?=.)    means followed by .
   ```
2. `NSScanner` is also a good method. See Apple's [NSScanner Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSScanner_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

   Example:

   ```
   let us = "http://google.com"
   let scanner = NSScanner(string:us)
   var scanned: NSString?

   if scanner.scanUpToString("://", intoString:nil) {
       scanner.scanString("://", intoString:nil)
       if scanner.scanUpToString(".", intoString:&scanned) {
           let result: String = scanned as String
           println("result: \(result)") // result: google
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the regular Expression

> ://.+.

it matches to

> ://google.

in this code:

```
var yourURL: NSString = "http://google.com" // this is your input and could be any URL
var regex: NSRegularExpression = NSRegularExpression.regularExpressionWithPattern("://.+\\.", options: NSRegularExpressionOptions.fromMask(UInt(0)), error: nil) // need double backspace because of backspace in String is \\ not \
var needleRange = regex.rangeOfFirstMatchInString(yourURL, options:NSMatchingOptions.Anchored, range: NSMakeRange(0, yourURL.length))
var needle: NSString = yourURL.substringWithRange(needleRange)
```

Now you can remove the first 3 symbols and the last one and you got

> google

with this code:

```
import Foundation

var halfURL: NSString = "://google."
var prefix: NSString = "://"
var suffix: NSString = "."
var needleRange: NSRange =  NSMakeRange(prefix.length, halfURL.length - prefix.length -     suffix.length)
var needle: NSString = halfURL.substringWithRange(needleRange)
// needle is now 'google'
```

Comment: When you're already using a regex, why not simply use capture group?

Comment: @DarkDust I do not know what you mean

Comment: A pattern like `://([^\\.]+)\\.`. If you don't know about capture groups yet, you might want read up on them as they are very important and can save you a lot of coding. Assuming `input` is an `NSString`: `let regex = NSRegularExpression.regularExpressionWithPattern("://([^\\.]+)\\.", options: NSRegularExpressionOptions.fromMask(UInt(0)), error: nil);
let matches = regex.matchesInString(input, options: NSMatchingOptions.fromMask(0), range: NSMakeRange(0, input.length));
if (matches?.count > 0) {
    result = input.substringWithRange(matches![0].rangeAtIndex(1))
}`

Comment: What this pattern means: `://` is obvious. `(` start capture group. `[^\\.]+` at least one character that is not a dot. `)` close capture group. `\\.` a dot. Now the group contains all the characters after `://` until the first dot.

Answer (score 1):

If your input is a valid URL, you can take advantage of the `NSURL` class to do the parsing for you:

```
var result : NSString?
let input = "http://test.com/blabla"

// Parse the string; might fail
let url : NSURL? = NSURL(string: input)

// Get the host part of the URL ("test.com")
let host = url?.host

// Split it up at the dots.
let hostParts = host?.componentsSeparatedByString(".")

// Assign the first part of the hostname if we were successful up to here.
if hostParts?.count > 0 {
    result = hostParts![0]
}
```

Bonus: ignore "www":

```
if hostParts?.count > 0 {
    if (hostParts![0] == "www" && hostParts!.count > 1) {
        result = hostParts![1]
    } else {
        result = hostParts![0]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For swift 3.0:

```
let us = "http://example.com"
let range = us.range(of:"(?<=://)[^.]+(?=.com)", options:.regularExpression)
if range != nil {
    let found = us.substring(with: range!)
    print("found: \(found)") // found: example
}
```